# Cakephp admin and user login separate

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to make an aplication where users can login normally and back-end where admins can login.

So far I created this:

routes.php

```
$prefix = 'admin';

Router::connect(
    "/{$prefix}/:plugin/:controller",
    array('action' => 'index', 'prefix' => $prefix, $prefix => true)
);
Router::connect(
    "/{$prefix}/:plugin/:controller/:action/*",
    array('prefix' => $prefix, $prefix => true)
);
Router::connect(
    "/{$prefix}/:controller",
    array('action' => 'index', 'prefix' => $prefix, $prefix => true)
);
Router::connect(
    "/{$prefix}/:controller/:action/*",
    array('prefix' => $prefix, $prefix => true)
);
```

AppController:

```
public $components = array(
    'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'pages',
            'action' => 'display'
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ),
        'authorize' => 'Controller',
        'authError' => 'Access denied! Did you really think that you can access that?'
    )
);

public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // Admin can access every action
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
        return true;
    }

    // Default deny
    return false;
}

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('display');
    //$this->recordActivity();
    if($this->request->prefix == 'admin'){
        $this->layout = 'admin';
    }   
}
```

With this when I try to access pages on front-end that needs auth it gives me login() action but when a try to access /admin it redirects me to /users/login.

I want to have two separate login systems with diferrent layouts. One for normal users and one for admin users.

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend two `login()` actions just for the sake of a different view. You can move the if statement from your `beforeFilter()` to `UsersController::login()` to set the layout correctly.  However, if you do want to proceed with separate actions, set the `AuthComponent::loginAction` property in `AppController::beforeFilter()` like:

```
if($this->request->prefix == 'admin'){
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'admin_login', 'plugin' => false);
}
```

where admin_login will be another action that you create in UsersController.

On a side note, I recommend using cake's default prefix routing as mentioned in the [book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing). It is very similar to what you have done but you won't have to manually create the routes. Also, as mentioned in there, to access /admin you will need to define a route like:

```
Router::connect(
    '/admin',
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true)
);
```